# Is there a command for exiting and re-entering a script?

Tags: python, json

Sorry for the other post, it had an error.

My simplified code:

```
#test
import json

x = {}

x['x'] = {'y': 1, 'z': 0}

with open('x.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(x, f)
```

and

```
#test2
import json

f = open('x.json')
x = json.load(f)

while x['x']['y'] > 0:
    x['x']['z'] = x['x']['z'] + 1
    x['x']['y'] = x['x']['y'] - 1

    if x['x']['y'] == 0:
        print(x['x']['z'])
        n = input("Number: ")
        while n.isdigit() == False:
            print("Not a number")
            n = input("Number: ")

        if n.isdigit() == True:
            x['x']['y'] = int(n)
            with open('x.json', 'w') as f:
                json.dump(x, f)
```

I have two codes so I don't overwrite the numbers of test2 with test

This is already kinda what I want, but my output for n = *4* and n = *5* is:

```
1
Number: 4
5
Number: 5
10
Number:
```

And so on...

But instead, I want the code to Exit completely and then start it again without me doing it manually. Kinda like:

```
1
Number: 4
```

*Code restarts*

```
5
Number: 5
```

*Code restarts*

```
5
Number: 10
```

and so on. Thank you :-)

Comment: Could you please elaborate _why_ you want to launch the script twice instead of looping the code inside?

Comment: I just noticed myself that that isn't really what I was going for, I will edit the post

Comment: @HampusLarsson It is edited :-)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly , You will have to create two separate scripts

**test1.py**

```
#test
import json
import os
x = {}

x['x'] = {'y': 1, 'z': 0}

with open('x.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(x, f)

os.system('python test2.py') # this line will run the second script
```

**test2.py**

```
import json

f = open('x.json')
x = json.load(f)

while x['x']['y'] > 0:
    x['x']['z'] = x['x']['z'] + 1
    x['x']['y'] = x['x']['y'] - 1

    if x['x']['y'] == 0:
        print(x['x']['z'])
        n = input("Number: ")
        while n.isdigit() == False:
            print("Not a number")
            n = input("Number: ")

        if n.isdigit() == True:
            x['x']['y'] = int(n)
            with open('x.json', 'w') as f:
                json.dump(x, f)
```

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the answer, but that's not what I meant. I already have two separate scripts that I started one after another instead of automatically. 

I meant that when test2.py comes to the end of the script, instead of repeating it like I did, the "Run-Window" should be completely restarted. That means instead of a Loop, I would like to have a "restart" of the problem, if that's logical.

Comment: @SkyThaKid So you want to break the loop after an input and exit the script test2 then start test2 again correct ?